# data-val-required not working, unless some other validator starts working

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I have a INPUT field with required field validator and other custom validation adapters,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.SomeClass.Name, new
                {

                    data_val = "true",
                    data_val_required = "Required Field Message",
                    data_val_customvalidator1 = "Message1",
                    data_val_customvalidator2 = "Message2",
                })
```

The problem I am having is, the required field validator is not working until and unless any other validator works

Scenario :-

Step 1 : User enters 1234, tabs out of the field and the field is validated
Step 2:  Selects the data entered in the above field and presses delete 
Step 3:  Required field validator doesn't work

But when user goes back to the field filled with data and already validated, and starts deleting one character at a time, other custom validators of the field starts working and makes the field invalid

Now if the user enters the right data and tabs out field gets validated, but now when user deletes the data completely like in step 2 above required field validation starts working!!!

So I am not able to understand why required field validator doesn't work until , some other validator works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this just by adding one line of code

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                    onfocusout: function(element) {
                        $(element).valid();
                    });
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Please have a look: jsfiddle.net/y4aoq8mr If to be more precise - it start working after you enter some value and then delete it. But from the very beginning it does not trigger validation error. And I still have not found the solution for this bug

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit overkill, but here's what works in my case (I gave up to make validate method working - submitHandler and all the rest did not work either at me):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':input[data-val]').bind('propertychange change click keyup input paste', function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        if ($element.valid()) {
            unhilightErrors($element);
        }
        else {
            hilightErrors($element);
        }
    });
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        if ($form.valid()) {
            var $button = $form.find(':submit');
            var loadingDelay = setTimeout(function () {
                $button.button('loading');
            }, 100);
            var formValues = $form.serialize();
            $.post($button.data('local-ajax'), formValues, function () {
                clearTimeout(loadingDelay);
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }
        else {
            hilightErrors();
        }
    });
    function hilightErrors($selector = undefined) {
        if ($selector && $selector.is(':input')) {
            $selector.addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        }
        else {
            $(':input.input-validation-error').addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('input-validation-error');
            $(':input.field-validation-error').addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('field-validation-error');
        }
    }
    function unhilightErrors($selector = undefined) {
        if (!$selector) {
            $selector = $(':input.alert-danger[data-val]');
        }
        $selector.removeClass('alert-danger');
    }
});
```